# Compilation with glibc 2.7 include path fails

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, glibc

I have compiled on my SLES 12.3 `g++ 7.3` into the `/FaF` directory and 
`glibc 2.27` is installed into the `/FaF/glibc` directory.

Compiling this very simple program with `g++ -c testAbs.cpp -I /FaF/glibc/include` fails horribly:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
int main( int argc, char * argv [] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return std::abs(std::atoi(argv[1]));
}
```

[See the long error list](https://gofile.io/?c=J2Zwlv). Below I inserted the first 15 lines - in total there are more than 300 lines of error messages.

Compiling it with `g++ -c testAbs.cpp` works fine. In this case it is using the system `glibc 2.22 include files`.

**I found out that it must somehow relate to the `g++ 7.3` installation. Using the system `g++ 4.8.5` works fine compiled like this `/usr/bin/g++-4.8 -c testAbs.cpp -I /FaF/glibc/include`**

What is going so horrible wrong compiling it with `g++ 7.3` using the path to the `glibc 2.27` include directories?

What am I messing up?

```
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:48:0,
                 from /FaF/include/c++/7.3/cmath:45,
                 from testAbs.cpp:11:
/FaF/glibc/include/bits/mathdef.h:19:3: error: #error "Never use <bits/mathdef.h> directly; include <complex.h> instead"
 # error "Never use <bits/mathdef.h> directly; include <complex.h> instead"
   ^~~~~
In file included from /FaF/include/c++/7.3/cstdlib:75:0,
                 from testAbs.cpp:10:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:95:1: error: ‘__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__BEGIN_DECLS’?
 __BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 __BEGIN_DECLS
/usr/include/stdlib.h:101:5: error: ‘div_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘size_t’?
   } div_t;
     ^~~~~
```

Comment: First, this is C++ program, please compile it with `g++ -c ...`. Also, your 2.27 header is picking up /usr/include/stdlib.h header, so I guess you're getting two glibc system messed up in some strange way.

Comment: Good to know. Another question is what dynamic linker etc is used during runtime. Care to run ldd on executable? It might work by chance - dynamic lnker from your current libc setup might be just compatible with 2.27

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I am using lot of rpath directives. Without it there is no way to make it work.

Comment: Good, glad to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the question was a minimized version of my include file. These are all include files which are needed in the project:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <forward_list>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <regex>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mysql/my_global.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

First, it could not be compiled in this order and I could not use the `cmath` include - due to the described error in the question.

I could fix it using these `g++` switches:

```
-nostdinc
-I /FaF/curl/include
-I /usr/include/mysql
-I /FaF/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7.3.0/include-fixed
-I /FaF/include/c++/7.3
-I /FaF/include/c++/7.3/x86_64-suse-linux/
-I /FaF/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7.3.0/include
-I /FaF/glibc/include/
-I /usr/include
```

`g++ -xc++ -E -v -` helped me to figure out which include paths are needed.

**THE ORDER DOES MATTER**

`-I /usr/include` must be last in the list!

Comment: Is there a reason for the order? Usually this never should matter. Did you further investigate it?

Comment: @Carsten Yeah, I opened a ticket but nobody really wants to help me there from the GNU development. I leave it how it is...