# Compilation in Windows Subsystem for Linux fails with error "Never use <bits/mathdef.h> directly; include <complex.h> instead"

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## Summary

I want to compile the `F5ToTEC` utility of the finite-element code [TACS](https://github.com/smdogroup/tacs), which I compiled on my Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

## What I've tried

I installed the [`TecIO` library from Tecplot](https://www.tecplot.com/products/tecio-library/) in the `tacs/extern/` directory, as indicated by the requirements of TACS (in my case I called the `tacs` folder `tacs-master`). I compiled the `TecIO` static libary (so not the `TecIO`-MPI version) as suggested by the include path of the `F5ToTEC` `Makefile` (see below).

In the `tacs-master/extern/f5totec/` directory I ran `make TACS_DIR=$TACS_DIR`, with `TACS_DIR=/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master` and I got the following error:

```
mpicxx  -fPIC -O3 -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/extern/metis/include/  -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/bpmat -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/elements -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/elements/dynamics -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/elements/basis -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/elements/shell -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/constitutive -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/functions -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/io -I/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/extern/tecio/teciosrc/ -I/usr/include -c f5totec.cpp -o f5totec.o
In file included from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:46,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:45,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/complex:44,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TacsComplexStep.h:18,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TACSObject.h:38,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/io/TACSFH5.h:22,
                 from f5totec.cpp:25:
/usr/include/bits/mathdef.h:19:3: error: #error "Never use <bits/mathdef.h> directly; include <complex.h> instead"
    19 | # error "Never use <bits/mathdef.h> directly; include <complex.h> instead"
    |   ^~~~~
In file included from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:70,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:45,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/complex:44,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TacsComplexStep.h:18,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TACSObject.h:38,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/io/TACSFH5.h:22,
                 from f5totec.cpp:25:
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:62:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    62 | __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:64:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    64 | __MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:79:22: error: 'sincos' has not been declared
    79 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
       |                      ^~~~~~
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:79:29: error: expected identifier before ',' token
    79 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
       |                             ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:80:3: error: expected identifier before '(' token
    80 |   (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__sinx, _Mdouble_ *__cosx));
       |   ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:80:57: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
    80 |   (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__sinx, _Mdouble_ *__cosx));
       |                                                         ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:95:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    95 | __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:104:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   104 | __MATHCALL_VEC (log,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:140:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   140 | __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ __y));
       |                ^
In file included from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:89,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:45,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/complex:44,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TacsComplexStep.h:18,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TACSObject.h:38,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/io/TACSFH5.h:22,
                 from f5totec.cpp:25:
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:62:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    62 | __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:64:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    64 | __MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:79:22: error: 'sincos' has not been declared
    79 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
       |                      ^~~~~~ 
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:79:29: error: expected identifier before ',' token
    79 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
       |                             ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:80:3: error: expected identifier before '(' token
    80 |   (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__sinx, _Mdouble_ *__cosx));
       |   ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:80:57: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
    80 |   (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__sinx, _Mdouble_ *__cosx));
       |                                                         ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:95:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    95 | __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:104:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   104 | __MATHCALL_VEC (log,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:140:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   140 | __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ __y));
       |                ^
In file included from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:133,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:45,
                 from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/complex:44,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TacsComplexStep.h:18,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TACSObject.h:38,
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/io/TACSFH5.h:22,
                 from f5totec.cpp:25:
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:62:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    62 | __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:64:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
    64 | __MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
       |                ^
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:79:22: error: 'sincos' has not been declared
    79 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,                                                                                                                                             
       |                      ^~~~~~                                                                                                                                         
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:79:29: error: expected identifier before ',' token                                                                                               
    79 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,                                                                                                                                             
       |                             ^                                                                                                                                       
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:80:3: error: expected identifier before '(' token                                                                                                
    80 |   (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__sinx, _Mdouble_ *__cosx));                                                                                                                 
       |   ^                                                                                                                                                                 
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:80:57: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token                                                              
    80 |   (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ *__sinx, _Mdouble_ *__cosx));                                                                                                                 
       |                                                         ^                                                                                                           
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:95:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token                                                              
    95 | __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (_Mdouble_ __x));                                                                                                                                   
       |                ^                                                                                                                                                    
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:104:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token                                                            
    104 | __MATHCALL_VEC (log,, (_Mdouble_ __x));                                                                                                                                   
        |                ^                                                                                                                                                    
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:140:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token                                                            
    140 | __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ __y));                                                                                                                    
        |                ^                                                                                                                                                    
In file included from /home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/complex:44,                                                                      
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TacsComplexStep.h:18,                                                                                                         
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/TACSObject.h:38,                                                                                                              
                 from /mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-master/src/io/TACSFH5.h:22,                                                                                                              
                 from f5totec.cpp:25:                                                                                                                                       
/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:180:11: error: '::cos' has not been declared                                      
    180 |   using ::cos;                                                                                                                                                            
        |           ^~~                                                                                                                                                       
/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:218:11: error: '::exp' has not been declared                                      
    218 |   using ::exp;                                                                                                                                                            
        |           ^~~                                                                                                                                                       
/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:334:11: error: '::log' has not been declared                                      
    334 |   using ::log;                                                                                                                                                            
        |           ^~~                                                                                                                                                       
/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:384:11: error: '::pow' has not been declared                                      
    384 |   using ::pow;                                                                                                                                                            
        |           ^~~                                                                                                                                                       
/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:421:11: error: '::sin' has not been declared                                      
    421 |   using ::sin;                                                                                                                                                            
        |           ^~~                                                                                                                                                       
/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:1065:11: error: '::double_t' has not been declared                               
    1065 |   using ::double_t;                                                                                                                                                       
         |           ^~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                  
/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-master/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:1066:11: error: '::float_t' has not been declared                                
    1066 |   using ::float_t;                                                                                                                                                        
         |           ^~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                   
make: *** [../../TACS_Common.mk:28: f5totec.o] Error 1
```

I am not an expert of compilation on linux systems and I struggle to understand why I get this error. For my understanding `complex.h` is called by `TacsComplexStep.h` and `mathdef.h` is called only as the last link of the chain.

## Codes

### `tacs-master/extern/f5totec/Makefile`

```
include ../../Makefile.in
include ../../TACS_Common.mk

default: TACS_CC_FLAGS=${TACS_OPT_CC_FLAGS} -I${TACS_DIR}/extern/tecio/teciosrc/ -I/usr/include
default: f5totec

f5totec: f5totec.o
    ${CXX} f5totec.o ../tecio/tecio.a ${TACS_LD_FLAGS} -o f5totec

clean:
    ${RM} f5totec *.o
```

### `tacs-master/Makefile.in`

```
TACS_DIR = ${HOME}/git/tacs
CXX = mpicxx
RM = rm -f
PYTHON = python
PYTHON_CONFIG = python-config

MAKE = make -j 8

AR_FLAGS = rcs

EXTRA_DEBUG_CC_FLAGS = -fPIC -g 
EXTRA_CC_FLAGS = -fPIC -O3

TACS_LD_CMD=-L${TACS_DIR}/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,${TACS_DIR}/lib -ltacs

SO_EXT=so
SO_LINK_FLAGS=-fPIC -shared

LAPACK_LIBS = -L/usr/lib/ -llapack -lpthread -lblas

METIS_INCLUDE = -I${TACS_DIR}/extern/metis/include/
METIS_LIB = ${TACS_DIR}/extern/metis/lib/libmetis.a
```

### `tacs-master/extern/f5totec/f5totec.cpp`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "TACSFH5.h"

#include "TECIO.h"

enum FileType { FULL=0, GRID=1, SOLUTION=2 };

enum ZoneType { ORDERED=0, FELINESEG, FETRIANGLE,
                FEQUADRILATERAL, FETETRAHEDRON, FEBRICK,
                FEPOLYGON, FEPOLYHEDRA };

int create_tec_file( char *data_info, char *var_names,
                     char *file_name, char *dir_name,
                     enum FileType _file_type ){
  INTEGER4 file_type = _file_type;
  INTEGER4 debug = 0;
  INTEGER4 variables_are_double = 0;
  return TECINI112(data_info, var_names, file_name, dir_name,
                   &file_type, &debug, &variables_are_double);
}

int create_fe_tec_zone( char *zone_name, ZoneType _zone_type,
                        int _num_points, int _num_elements,
                        int use_strands=0,
                        double solution_time=0.0 ){
  if (_zone_type == ORDERED ||
      _zone_type == FEPOLYGON ||
      _zone_type == FEPOLYHEDRA ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create finite element zone with given \
zone type\n");
    return -1;
  }

  INTEGER4 zone_type = _zone_type;
  INTEGER4 num_points = _num_points;
  INTEGER4 num_elements = _num_elements;
  INTEGER4 num_faces = 0; // For all zones allowed here
  INTEGER4 icmax = 0, jcmax = 0, kcmax = 0; // Ignored
  INTEGER4 strand_id = 0;
  INTEGER4 parent_zone = 0;
  INTEGER4 is_block = 1; // Apparently this always needs to be 1
  // These are only for cell-based finite element data - we use node-based
  INTEGER4 num_face_connections = 0;
  INTEGER4 face_neighbour_mode = 0;
  INTEGER4 total_num_face_nodes = 0;
  INTEGER4 num_connected_boundary_faces = 0;
  INTEGER4 total_num_boundary_connections = 0;
  INTEGER4 *passive_var_list = NULL; // No passive variables
  INTEGER4 *value_location = NULL; // All values are nodal values
  INTEGER4 *share_var_from_zone = NULL;
  INTEGER4 share_con_from_zone = 0;

  // If we're using strands, set the strand ID
  if (use_strands){
    strand_id = 1;
  }

  return TECZNE112(zone_name, &zone_type, &num_points, &num_elements,
                   &num_faces, &icmax, &jcmax, &kcmax,
                   &solution_time, &strand_id, &parent_zone, &is_block,
                   &num_face_connections, &face_neighbour_mode,
                   &total_num_face_nodes, &num_connected_boundary_faces,
                   &total_num_boundary_connections,
                   passive_var_list, value_location,
                   share_var_from_zone, &share_con_from_zone);
}

int write_tec_double_data( int _len, double *data ){
  INTEGER4 len = _len;
  INTEGER4 is_double = 1;
  return TECDAT112(&len, data, &is_double);
}

int write_tec_float_data( int _len, float *data ){
  INTEGER4 len = _len;
  INTEGER4 is_double = 0;
  return TECDAT112(&len, data, &is_double);
}

int write_con_data( int * con_data ){
  return TECNOD112(con_data);
}

int close_tec_file(){
  return TECEND112();
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  // Check if we're going to use strands or not
  int use_strands = 0;
  for ( int k = 0; k < argc; k++ ){
    if (strcmp(argv[k], "--use_strands") == 0){
      use_strands = 1;
    }
  }

  // Convert hdf5 file argv[1] to tecplot file argv[2]
  if (argc == 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, no input files\n");
    return (1);
  }

  for ( int k = 1; k < argc; k++ ){
    char *infile = new char[ strlen(argv[k])+1 ];
    strcpy(infile, argv[k]);

    FILE *fp = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (fp){
      fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
      delete [] infile;
      continue;
    }

    // Set the output file
    char *outfile = new char[ strlen(infile)+5 ];
    int len = strlen(infile);
    int i = len-1;
    for ( ; i >= 0; i-- ){
      if (infile[i] == '.'){ break; }
    }
    strcpy(outfile, infile);
    strcpy(&outfile[i], ".plt");

    printf("Trying to convert FH5 file %s to tecplot file %s\n",
           infile, outfile);

    char data_info[] = "Created by f5totec";
    char dir_name[] = "."; // We'll be working with the current directory
    int tec_init = 0;      // Tecplot initialized flag

    // Open the FH5 file for reading
    TACSFH5File * file = new TACSFH5File(MPI_COMM_SELF);
    file->incref();

    if (!file->openFile(infile)){
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open the file %s\n", infile);
      return (1);
    }

    // Retrieve all the data from the file including the
    // variables, connectivity and component numbers
    double solution_time = 0.0;
    int *element_comp_num = NULL;
    int *conn = NULL;
    double *data = NULL;
    float *float_data = NULL;
    int conn_dim = 0, num_elements = 0, num_points = 0, num_variables = 0;
    file->firstZone();
    do {
      // Find the zone corresponding to all the data
      const char *zone_name, *var_names;
      TACSFH5File::FH5DataType dtype;
      int dim1, dim2;

      if (!file->getZoneInfo(&zone_name, &var_names, &dtype, &dim1, &dim2)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, zone not defined\n");
        break;
      }

      if (strcmp(zone_name, "components") == 0){
        void *vdata;
        if (file->getZoneData(&zone_name, &var_names, &dtype,
                              &dim1, &dim2, &vdata)){
          element_comp_num = (int*)vdata;
        }
      }
      else if (strcmp(zone_name, "connectivity") == 0){
        num_elements = dim1;
        conn_dim = dim2;
        void *vdata;
        if (file->getZoneData(&zone_name, &var_names, &dtype,
                              &dim1, &dim2, &vdata)){
          conn = (int*)vdata;
        }
      }
      else if (strncmp(zone_name, "data", 4) == 0){
        // Try to retrieve the solution time - this may fail if an older
        // version of the F5 file is used
        if (!(sscanf(zone_name, "data t=%lf", &solution_time) == 1)){
          solution_time = 0.0;
        }

        // Initialize the tecplot file with the variables
        char *vars = new char[ strlen(var_names)+1 ];
        strcpy(vars, var_names);
        create_tec_file(data_info, vars,
                        outfile, dir_name, FULL);
        tec_init = 1;
        delete [] vars;

        // Retrieve the data
        void *vdata;
        if (file->getZoneData(&zone_name, &var_names, &dtype,
                              &dim1, &dim2, &vdata)){
          num_points = dim1;
          num_variables = dim2;
          if (dtype == TACSFH5File::FH5_DOUBLE){
            data = (double*)vdata;
          }
          else if (dtype == TACSFH5File::FH5_FLOAT){
            float_data = (float*)vdata;
          }
        }
      }
    } while (file->nextZone());

    if (!(element_comp_num && conn && (data || float_data))){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error, data, connectivity or \
component numbers not defined in file\n");
    }

    // Set the element type to use
    ZoneType zone_type;
    if (conn_dim == 2){
      zone_type = FELINESEG;
    }
    else if (conn_dim == 8){
      zone_type = FEBRICK;
    }
    else {
      zone_type = FEQUADRILATERAL;
    }

    int num_comp = file->getNumComponents();

    int *reduced_points = new int[ num_points ];
    int *reduced_conn = new int[ conn_dim*num_elements ];
    double *reduced_data = NULL;
    float *reduced_float_data = NULL;
    if (data){
      reduced_data = new double[ num_points ];
    }
    else if (float_data){
      reduced_float_data = new float[ num_points ];
    }

    for ( int k = 0; k < num_comp; k++ ){
      // Count up the number of elements that use the connectivity
      char *comp_name = file->getComponentName(k);
      //printf("Converting zone %d: %s at time %g\n",
      // k, comp_name, solution_time);

      memset(reduced_points, 0, num_points*sizeof(int));
      memset(reduced_conn, 0, conn_dim*num_elements*sizeof(int));

      int npts = 1, nelems = 0;
      for ( int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ ){
        if (element_comp_num[i] == k){
          for ( int j = 0; j < conn_dim; j++ ){
            int pt = conn[conn_dim*i + j];

            if (reduced_points[pt] == 0){
              reduced_points[pt] = npts;
              npts++;
            }

            reduced_conn[conn_dim*nelems + j] = reduced_points[pt];
          }
          nelems++;
        }
      }

      npts--;

      if (nelems > 0 && npts > 0){
        create_fe_tec_zone(comp_name, zone_type, npts, nelems,
                           use_strands, solution_time);

        for ( int j = 0; j < num_variables; j++ ){
          if (reduced_data){
            for ( int i = 0; i < num_points; i++ ){
              if (reduced_points[i] > 0){
                reduced_data[reduced_points[i]-1] = data[i*num_variables + j];
              }
            }
            write_tec_double_data(npts, reduced_data);
          }
          else if (reduced_float_data){
            for ( int i = 0; i < num_points; i++ ){
              if (reduced_points[i] > 0){
                reduced_float_data[reduced_points[i]-1] =
                  float_data[i*num_variables + j];
              }
            }
            write_tec_float_data(npts, reduced_float_data);
          }
        }

        write_con_data(reduced_conn);
      }
    }

    if (tec_init){
      close_tec_file();
    }
    file->close();
    file->decref();

    // Clean up memory
    delete [] reduced_points;
    delete [] reduced_conn;
    delete [] reduced_data;

    delete [] data;
    delete [] conn;
    delete [] element_comp_num;

    delete [] infile;
    delete [] outfile;
  }

  MPI_Finalize();

  return (0);
}
```

### `tacs-master/src/TacsComplexStep.h`

```
#ifndef TACS_COMPLEX_STEP_H
#define TACS_COMPLEX_STEP_H

#include <complex>

inline double TacsRealPart( const std::complex<double>& c ){
  return real(c);
}

inline double TacsImagPart( const std::complex<double>& c ){
  return imag(c);
}

inline double TacsRealPart( const double& r ){
  return r;
}

inline std::complex<double> fabs( const std::complex<double>& c ){
  if (real(c) < 0.0){
    return -c;
  }
  return c;
}

#endif // TACS_COMPLEX_STEP_H
```

**Edit**: following the indications of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49146920/6583606) I tried to run `mpicxx -xc++ -E -v -` in `tacs-master/extern/f5totec/`. I got the following output, however I don't know what I should do with it.

[image]

Comment: It is suspicious that you appear to be using some sources and tools from inside an anaconda3 environment, but others from outside.  In particular, if you're getting an admixture of headers from different versions of glibc then that very well might explain the error messages you ask about.  I'm afraid I can't really help you with the details, however.

Comment: Thanks for your comment John. I am definitely a newbie on these topics, so I am not sure I am completely understanding your comment. What do you mean by tools from inside and outside the anaconda3 environment? Are you referring to the lines in the error `In the file included from...`? And how can I recognize the different versions of glibc?

Comment: Anaconda provides Python binaries and a collection of Python packages and modules, together with support libraries and management tools, including tools for installing packages containing native extensions.  The C compiler that your `mpicc` command is choosing is part of an Anaconda installation.  The working directory for your build is *outside* that distribution, and I would not ordinarily expect Anaconda's C compiler to be appropriate for building an external module.

Comment: On the other hand, your `tacs-master/` directory appears to be *in* anaconda.  I'm not sure where your `mpicc` is coming from, but if it is not coming from anaconda itself, then it is probably incorrect for it to be using the `gcc` from there.  I'm not sure what to make of all of that, but if F5ToTEC is available for installation via Anaconda's `conda` package manager then that's very likely how you should be trying to get it.